# Mysqli Output to a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So my goal is to output some mysql info to a table. I want it to start a new column every 18th record. Here is my current code:

```
$hostname = "localhost"; //SET SERVER/HOSTNAME
    $dbusername = "username"; //SET DATABASE USERNAME
    $dbname = "database"; //SET DATABASE NAME
    $dbpassword =  "password"; //SET DATABASE USERNAME
    $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname); 

    if (!$link)
    { 
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    } 

    $continent='Africa';

    //GET AFRICA Countries
    $sql = "SELECT country FROM countries WHERE continent = '$continent';"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    if (!result) 
    { 
        echo 'Error: ', $mysqli->error;
    }
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $country = $row['country'];
        echo "$country<br>";
    }
```

Right now it just outputs the list in a straight column, but I want it to start a new column after x amount of times. Is that possible to do?

Comment: It can be done but it is easier to start a new row after x amount of times.

Comment: Ok and how would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

As discussed in comments it can be done but it is easier to start a new row after x amount of times.

1. count total rows using [`$result->num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)
2. calculate columns by dividing total rows by required rows
3. display required columns using table
4. use [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to generate new row if `$i % $columns ==0`

TRY

```
$requiredRows= 18; 
$rows = $result->num_rows ;
$columns = ceil($rows/$requiredRows);
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo "<table><tr><td>";
    }
    elseif ($i % $columns) {// <> 0
        echo "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>\n";
    }else{//$i % $columns == 0
        echo "</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>\n";
    }
    echo $row['country'];
    $i++;
}
```

You can also hard code column number if required.